# Cartogram3 plugin for QGIS still working?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, cartogram

Is the [Cartogram3 plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cartogram3/) still working? I get an error message every time I try to run it and have heard from others that it may no longer be operational.

Comment: Plugin to what? What error message do you get? Please try and add this information to give your question a chance of being answered!

Comment: Please always state which software you use

Comment: I'm not sure about the plugin - using an older version of QGIS 3.x, it should still work. TO create cartograms, another option is the great OpenSource standalone application Scapetoad: http://scapetoad.choros.place/ - it's easy to use and you can export the results to reimport it to QGIS.

Answer (score 5):

I'm able to run the plugin on QGIS 3.16 without any issue.

The recipe to install. Download code from repo https://github.com/austromorph/cartogram3 using exactly the following link https://github.com/austromorph/cartogram3/archive/refs/heads/master.zip to get a ZIP file. Then, open QGIS, go to "Plugins" > "Manage and Install Plugins..." > "Install from ZIP". Then, select the downloaded ZIP file and click on button "Install Plugin". Then go to "All" to tick "cartogram3" like below.

[image]

Close the plugins manager. Create a new QGIS project (no need to save, just for demo purpose)
Now, in the menu, go to "Vector" > "Cartogram" > "Add sample dataset" to see the following

[image]

Again, do "Vector" > "Cartogram" > "Compute cartogram". Then, choose the following in the menu

[image]

Do "Ok", wait and see the result

[image]

You may wonder why I choose to install from github repo ZIP file instead of official QGIS plugins. It's because of below clues

[image]

[image]

On the Github repository (1st screenshot), the code has been updated 4 months ago whereas the plugin has been published last time on "Sept. 24, 2019, 2:45 a.m." according to https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cartogram3/

Your issue may not be related but at least, you better understand my approach.